# VS2013 intellisense code completion

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense, code-completion, visual-studio-2013

First I thought it was a problem of VS2013 RC/beta but now I installed VS2013 RTM and still have the same problem: code completion does only open after I execute it manually by strg+space. How can I turn on auto open the windows after typed e.g. a point?

Comment: Turned out that an old reshaper installation was the problem. One can make everething work as expected by Tools->Import and export settins->Reset all settings

Comment: He might not even have to do that.  Check out the solution by Patrick Desjardins in this thread.  Those two check boxes were turned off by Resharper for me, so after I didn't use it any longer, all I had to do was make sure those two check boxes were enabled.

Comment: If you think this could be a Resharper artefact, such as because you have inadvertently imported settings through source control from your dev machine that has Resharper installed, then: Tools>Options>Text-Editor>C# and then check "Auto list members" and "Parameter Info".

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When intellisense is displayed is a language specific setting.  If you're asking about c# then you want to check the following

- Tools -> Options
- Text Editor -> C# -> Intellisense
- Ensure "Show completion list after a character is typed" is checked

If you're using a different language please update the question and I'll try to point you in the right direction

Comment: Is this also possible for javascript or typescript?

Comment: It does also not work for c# when i akcivated the option. I did a clean uninstall and new installation.

Comment: Turned out that an old reshaper installation was the problem. One can make everething work as expected by Tools->Import and export settins->Reset all settings

Comment: @zoidbergi thanks for that - I had exactly the same problem and thought I was going mad!

Comment: right. I have done this, and nothing has changed. I had to close and reopen Visual Studio 2013 and now `CTRL + SPACE` is working fine to autocomplete class properties.

Answer (score 57):

Be sure that your IntelliSense is activated [image]

```
Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Statement completion
```

Then, be sure Auto list members is checked and Parameter Information.

Comment: This is the fix that did it for me.  Thank you very much!  I was getting pretty frustrated and didn't want to reset all the settings.

Comment: Thank you! For some reason my Intellisense just randomly stopped working. This did the trick!

Answer (score 9):

This happened after uninstalling Resharper 8.x (I don't see the point given VS 2013's advances), so I'd chalk this to an unclean resharper uninstall.

The solution is very quick though:

- Open VS2013
- Tools -> Import and Export settings
- Reset all settings
- Visual C#

Comment: Nice one, simple, fast and effective! In my case I had just installed VS2013 alongside VS2012 (which already had Resharper 8 installed). Probably related.

Answer (score 5):

TOOLS->Import and Export Settings Wizard->Reset all settings->select “No, just reset settings, overwriting my current settings”->Choose a Default Collection of settings. Check it again.

Answer (score 3):

If none of the above suggestions work, check if you have an extension Web Essentials installed. Try removing it (and install again). Web Essentials has caused my intellisense to stop working multiple times and a simple re-install always fixes the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Do not need reset all settings. I had a same problem but i' ve have just solved it.

1. Run resharper.setup.exe
2. do not click uninstall or repair. just click reinstall it
3. after installation it will be ok

good luck:)

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me after uninstalling Resharper 8.x

Solution:

Tools -> Options
Text Editor -> C# -> Intellisense
Ensure "Show completion list after a character is typed" is **un**checked

Tools -> Options
Text Editor -> C# -> Intellisense
Ensure "Show completion list after a character is typed" is **checked**

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me (using Visual Studio 2013 w/ ReSharper 8.0.2):

1. Tools->Options->ReSharper
2. Click "Suspend Now"
3. Click "Resume Now"

Answer (score 0):

1: Try to use **ReSharper 8.0.2** Best Code analysic, completion tool

2: **Tools > Options > Text Editor > All Language >** Make Check on Auto List members

Answer (score 0):

Method 1

1. List item
2. Tools -> Options
3. Text Editor -> C# -> Intellisense
4. Ensure "Show completion list after a character is typed" is checked

Method 2(for me after uninstall resharper)

1. List item
2. Open VS2013
3. Tools -> Import and Export settings
4. Reset all settings
5. General/Your prefer language(like Visual C#)