# VS2013 Intellisense constantly stops working

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, intellisense

I have Visual Studio 2013 with no plugins or anything fancy. Whenever I'm coding, every so often (maybe once every half hour) intellisense randomly stops completing my sentences or popping up at all when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

I have tried Tools->Import and export settings->Reset all settings but it did not help. The issue came right back.

The only thing that solves it for me now is to close VS and reopen it. But as you can imagine, this is extremely frustrating.

Comment: I have this same problem and I also just close and reopen. I will be interested to see if there is a better solution to this

Comment: I had two files open, one where I was doing a linq select statement from a big proxied class into a smaller class, and another file with both the big and small class defined in it. Whenever I rename a property in the small class, intellisense seems to fail.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual studio 2013 intellisense stops working for ASP.NET MVC5 Controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21471887/visual-studio-2013-intellisense-stops-working-for-asp-net-mvc5-controllers)

Comment: Yes, it's always been problematic. It can get confused, I believe. It is, after all, doing a pretty complex job on-the-fly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like my issue cleared up after deleting the settings folder from my previous VS2010 installation. I followed the instructions here (Also applies to VS2013): http://www.haneycodes.net/visual-studio-2012-intellisense-not-working-solved/

In case URL breaks:

1. Open the start menu and type “%AppData%” and press enter to get to your Application Data Folder.
2. Either you were automatically placed in the “Roaming” folder or you weren’t. If you weren’t, go to the “Roaming” folder.
3. Open the “Microsoft” folder.
4. Open the “VisualStudio” folder.
5. Here you’ll see a folder titled “11.0” (the VS 2012 folder) and probably also “10.0” (the VS 2010 folder).
6. DELETE (or rename) the “10.0” folder. Note that you can now kiss your Visual Studio 2010 settings and preferences goodbye (your projects will be safe and sound).
7. DELETE (or rename) all other folders that are not the “11.0” folder, assuming you used to have Visual Studio 2008 or whatever.

Now restart Visual Studio 2012 and you should be good to go!

Comment: Nah. I never had VS2010 or VS2012 installed. I installed 8.1 with VS2013 from fresh and it keeps doing it.

Answer (score 40):

I was having the same problem and this seemed to work for me.

http://omegacoder.com/?p=1008

Basically, go to Tools >> Options >> Text Editor >> All Languages >> General and make sure that both `Auto list members` and `Parameter information` are checked (not the half-checked/square state).

Comment: Worked for me, this happened after I had installed typescript 1.5 for Vs2013

Comment: Thanks dude. Worked for me too. ;)

Answer (score 31):

This is still happening in VS2013 update 4 (I have a WPF project using C#).

This was relatively easy to fix by closing then reopening the file not the whole project.

Comment: I have this issue as well, and simply closing/reopening the file is sufficient to fix the issue

Comment: I have noticed this problem since VS2010, continuing in VS 2013.  I didn't know that simply reopening the file would fix it, so this is great!  I want to add that the cases where Intellisense stops working don't seem quite random.  Intellisense commonly stops working when the code is in a non-compilable state (when red squiggles appear).  I have come to accept this as a fact of life, and I've learned that it tends to recover automatically when the errors are fixed.  Sometimes it doesn't recover, and this is what's frustrating.  Now I know that reopening the file is a fairly easy fix.

Answer (score 8):

For me, Unloading and Reloading a project fixes MVC cshtml intellisense. Right-click project, click Unload. Right click grayed out project, click Reload.

Just to be clear, this problem only happens to me when in C# MVC views, only when checked into TFS.

I have also submitted this as a bug to Microsoft, see https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/932855/vs-2013-c-default-mvc-template-breaks-upon-checkin-to-tfs-2010

Comment: Thank you so much! That totally fixed my intellisense problems. Never knew about the load/unload feature. Thanks :))

Answer (score 7):

try to delete the .suo file of your solution. It worked well for me.

Answer (score 4):

The first thing I should mention is that this hasn't happened since I've upgraded my RAM. I was at 4GB when this was happening. Often had multiple instances open as well as SQL Server.

I'm finding this seems to happen when I copy/paste controls on a page. Another side affect of this is that the designer.(cs/vb/xx) file is not updated right away and I don't have access to those controls in code behind.

I've tried a handful of things and here's a summary of what I've found so far:

- If only 1 file/window appears to be affected, close/reopen that file.

If that doesn't work... in Visual Studio:

1. Click Tools->Options->Text Editor->All Languages->General
2. Uncheck "Auto list members"
3. Uncheck "Parameter information"
4. Check "Auto list members" (yes, the one you just unchecked)
5. Check "Parameter information" (again, the one you just unchecked)
6. Click OK

If this doesn't work, here's a few more steps to try:

1. If still not working, close all windows and reopen
2. If still not working, close/reopen solution
3. If still not working, restart VS.

(I haven't yet figured out why more drastic steps are required in some cases.)

**For C++ projects:**
MSDN has a few things to try: [MSDN suggestions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ks1ka3t6%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

The corrupt `.ncb` file seems most likely. Note that in VS2013 and later, it is the `.sdf` file, which can be found in the root folder. Try searching for `filename:*.sdf`.

From MSDN:

1. Close the solution.
2. Delete the `.ncb` file.
3. Reopen the solution. (This creates a new `.ncb` file.)

Notes:

- Tested in VS 2013/2015

Logging possible causes:

- Copy/pasting controls in a source page. I found that my `designer.vb` file didn't update from this, either.
- Copy/pasting code from another page that caused an error because the code copied referred to a control that wasn't on the page I was pasting to.
- C++ project has corrupt `.ncb` file

Answer (score 2):

Like cacau says, you must first do a clean of the entire solution. Then restart VS rebuild the entire solution.
This sometimes happens when you are using Entity Framework or WCF services (Or the combination)

VS generates a lot of files then that contain code (the service reference for example). When you regenerate that code (And for example you are running a web project) sometimes you forget to stop the site. Then VS can't overwrite every file. Resulting in a global intellisense failure.

Comment: The "have you tried turning it off and on again" approach never disappointed me!

Comment: -1 It has nothing to do with Entity or WCF. It happens to me on new MVC solutions when I am just messing around trying to design simple models, but also happens on massive projects where we don't use Entity or WCF. You dont need to clean and rebuild, just close and reopen VS fixes it every time.

Comment: have you installed latest SP packs? Is everything up to date? Otherwise try reinstalling VS2013 entirely. Might help.

Answer (score 2):

For me, the problem happens when I have two instances of same solution opened.  On one of them I'm running Tests, while on the other I am making tweaks to code.  Intellisense will quit working on me usually after I've run some tests and stopped the debug session manually.

The solution for me is to close all VS windows and reopen...

Answer (score 1):

Did you try a clean build on your project?

VS might have become confused with some of its generated files..

Comment: I haven't yet. I just tried deleting the settings folder from VS2010 (http://www.haneycodes.net/visual-studio-2012-intellisense-not-working-solved/) but if that doesn't work, I will try your suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

None of the solutions in this thread worked for me. 
what worked was that I deleted everything in the packages folder. when I rebuilt the solution, nuget got the latest versions of all the folders I deleted, and intellisense started working fine.
If I am not mistaken, the problem initially was caused by the contents of the "Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0" folder, but I dont know why.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this problem in one file, make sure that this file is included in your project. **Right Click the file, Select Include In Project**. If the file is not included in your project, VS will treat it as a normal text file.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the instructions given in response to the question : [Visual Studio 2012 - Intellisense sometimes disappearing / broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13375961/visual-studio-2012-intellisense-sometimes-disappearing-broken) (thanks to SajjadHashmi and others). I've copied the steps I followed (which worked for me) here in an attempt to be helpful.

1: `Close all the tabs` and open your file again. *(Thanks to russds)*

2: `Clean the Build` > `Close the Solution` > `Restart Visual Studio` > `Open the Solution` again

Further steps are listed if you follow the above link but some seem to no longer apply to Visual Studio 2013 (e.g. refresh Local Cache for intellisense).

I know that these steps involve restarted Visual Studio (which you are explicitly trying to avoid) but for those who find your question (such as me) a potential solution might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else fell into the black hole I did ... I too suffered from this issue but NONE of the above solutions worked for me. Eventually I figured out that somehow the opening <body> tag had been deleted from my .Master page and that was causing all my .aspx pages to lose 95% of the Intellisense code hinting. Once I added the missing <body> back to my .Master page, the Intellisense finally started working in my .aspx pages again! Hope this helps someone ... just cost me 1.5 hours!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes none of suggestions here works - at least that happened to me.
But don't rush with configuration resetting, cleaning up visual studio configuration files and so on. If clean/re-build + vs restart does not work - problem might be in code itself.

In my case (vs2013) I had C++ class exposed in .h like this:

```
class MyClass: ...
{
    ....
    DLL_EXPORT returnArgs function(InParameters)
}
```

where DLL_EXPORT is defined as :

```
#define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
```

Same function in .cpp:

```
returnArgs MyClass::function(InParameters)
{

}
```

vs2013 was refusing to jump between function definition / implementation.
Reason seemed to be DLL_EXPORT macro - I've written function like this:

```
DLL_EXPORT returnArgs MyClass::function(InParameters)
{

}
```

After that intellisense started to work again.

It's possible also to remove that define or wipe it out - according to visual studio documentation `__INTELLISENSE__` - but that define did not work for me for some reason. Code snipet like this:

```
#ifdef __INTELLISENSE__
    #define DLL_EXPORT
#else
    #define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#endif
```

Please comment if you understand why this does not work.

In vs2015 this issue seems to be fixed, but there are other problems with vs2015.

Answer (score 0):

None of these things worked for me. After lot of struggle I found why it was not working for me. I always had multiple solutions open in my machine. For suppose, One solution is for front-end layer and another solution is for back-end layer.

When it hits breakpoint kept in backend service layer intellisense was not showing up. After I closed all other solutions and rebuild the solution where I wanted to debug, everything worked fine.

There could be other reasons, but this worked for me and wanted to let this community know and it may help someone.

EDIT: Few times "delete all breakpoints" and adding again worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and in my case it was the same file being open twice. For example I have dev\include\myfile.h AND dev\include\myfile.h\ (note the backslash, making this a unique string).
This happens when I use F12 to find a symbol in an include file, but also have the original .h file open already; Visual Studio opens up a duplicate file, which is really the same file.

When saving either of the two instances, the changed file date will be noticed and I get a popup asking whether I want to reload the other instance. More problematic seems that it also confuses IntelliSense. I just tried closing all duplicate instanced files, and IntelliSense started working again without restarting or reloading anything.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to fix my problem by solution [VS2013 Intellisense constantly stops working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21929028/vs2013-intellisense-constantly-stops-working/21930214#21930214)

But it did not work for me.

Solution that worked for me is **off/on** *Auto list members*

*Go to Tools > Options > Text Editor > General*

[image]