# getting auto completion in cshtml files in asp.net mvc application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am creating an asp.net mvc application, when I create some views with razor synthax, I am not getting auto completion so I have to look online for the documentation, I would like to know what things I have to activate to get the autocompletion for example for the html helpers.

For information I am using vs 2012 ultimate.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Sorry, I clicked to fast on the relative tags.

Comment: I think , you will have your solution in this topic :)


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19438355/vs2013-intellisense-code-completion